# Publishing a WCF Service Library Succeeds, But the .scv Is Missing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, iis-7

I've searched for questions addressing this exact issue, but failed to find something helpful.

I had a WCF Service Library project which held the contract and the service implementation. I published the service to the IIS using the 'publish' option in VS 2013 and everything worked fine.

I now moved the service contract to another assembly, but kept the namespace.
When I publish the service it says 'Publish Succeeded', but I don't see the .svc file in the designated path (where it used to be), and also I can't access the service in the browser.

I'm pretty sure it should be possible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the publish profiles and their locations.

Comment: The publish profiles remain in the same location in both cases. The only difference I see is that the .svc file is missing from the publish XMLs in the second case. Adding the file entry manually into the XML didn't solve the problem..

Comment: I have several options and I manged to un-publish .svc file. I have gone to Properties Window of the `Service.cs` class and changed the Build Action to `Embedded resource` when it should be `Compile`. Could you check the Properties Window for Build Actions?

Comment: The Build Action is 'compile'

Comment: I am sorry my friend. I have made all your changes, created other assembly, moved interfaces, built, published. Everything seems fine here.

Comment: I know it SHOULD work. But it doesn't. I managed to reproduce this exact same behavior on another machine. Weird.